# PHP protected download manager

Tags: php, http, download

I am building a small download module for a larger project I am currently working on, and have run into a bit of an issue. Although it works perfectly for small files, when the browser (any browser) begins downloading a larger file, it simply loads like any page would, and then in the last few seconds "downloads" the whole file (regardless of size) almost instantly. I have gone through HTTP 1.1 standard over and over, and seem to be following them to the letter. One thought that instantly comes to mind is when PHP is actually sending data to the client. The answer SHOULD be as the script runs - I use this principle in other long scripts for debugging.

Here is the relevant piece of code (there is much more too it of course, but this is where headers and output is actually sent:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-length: $size");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileData['name'].'"');    
for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i+=$step)
{
    $content = fread($file, $step);
    if ($content === false)
        $content = "";

    echo $content;
}
die();
```

Any ideas? I have a feeling this is an obvious issue I just can't see from staring at this block for so long.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the loop? could just use [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile)

Comment: Why don't you use `readfile` or x-sendfile?

Comment: a habit more than anything, I like having control over IO operations, it's why I prefer lower level languages like C. From what I read it comes up to the same thing

Comment: make sure output buffering is disabled. check via phpinfo() and disable via config, or at script runtime via `while(ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();`

Comment: GOOD GOD, can I buy you a beer rambo? That was it!

Comment: also, fread arg#2 is max bytes, not min bytes. Your for loop assumes it will read max bytes.

Comment: @user: you have no control over the real i/o operations anyways. All you're doing is sending data to the webserver, which will do its own buffering and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, this function will return false if the passed file is a directory or not found. it will also remove spaces from the file name so as not to break the download. its also possible to limit the download speed by changing `1024` and it will handle files over 2GB.

```
<?php 
function download($file){
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        if(is_dir($file)){return false;}
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.str_ireplace(' ','_',basename($file)).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: '.sprintf("%u", filesize($file)));

        @ob_clean();
        $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
        $chunksize=(sprintf("%u", (filesize($file))/1024));

        set_time_limit(0);
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            echo fgets($handle, $chunksize);
            flush();
        }
        fclose($handle);
        die;
    }else{return false;}
    return;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the tools, stop reinventing the wheel. [pecl_http](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.http-send-file.php) has been around for some time now.

```
<?php
http_send_content_disposition("document.pdf", true);
http_send_content_type("application/pdf");
http_throttle(0.1, 2048);
http_send_file("../report.pdf");
?>
```

This code sample is fast, robust and it gives you multiple feature bonus :

- bandwidth throttling
- cache and headers management
- partial and resumable download

Comment: "A good programmer can find tools to do any job. A great programmer can use the tools he already has."